# wxWidgets - Write all folders into a listbox

Tags: c++, listbox, directory, wxwidgets

I know there's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166016/making-a-list-of-folders-in-a-directory-with-wxwidgets) with a similar question but it doesn't work the way it's supposed to be there. I'm fairly new to c++ and wxWidgets so please as easy as possible.

```
void dlgMain::getAllDirectories(wxString Path)
{
wxDir dir(Path);
wxString dirName = dir.GetName();
wxArrayString dirList;

dir.GetAllFiles(dirName, &dirList, wxEmptyString, wxDIR_DIRS | wxDIR_FILES);

m_lbDir->Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < dirList.size(); i++)
{
    //wxMessageBox(dirList[i].c_str());
    m_lbDir->Append(dirList[i].c_str());
}
}
```

*Path* contains the path to a directory(i.e. "C:\Folder1\"). I want to list all folders(not files) within *Folder1* into my listbox. My Problem is that it doesn't work with GetAllFiles() the way I want to. It gives back all directories, subdirectories and files and lists them with their full path. I've tried using just *wxDIR_DIRS* as a Filter but that won't return anything? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to get the directories, and not the sub-directories or files, then you can create a class derived from `wxDirTraverser` to do that as follows:

```
#include <wx/dir.h>
class wxDirectoriesEnumerator : public wxDirTraverser {
public:
    wxArrayString *dirs;
    wxDirectoriesEnumerator(wxArrayString* dirs_)  {
        dirs=dirs_;
    }
    //This function will be called when a file is found
    virtual wxDirTraverseResult OnFile(const wxString& filename) {
        //Do nothing, continue with the next file or directory
        return wxDIR_CONTINUE;
    }
    //This function will be called when a directory is found
    virtual wxDirTraverseResult OnDir(const wxString& dirname) {
        //Add the directory to the results
        dirs->Add(dirname);
        //Do NOT enter this directory
        return wxDIR_IGNORE;
    }
};
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
wxArrayString dirList;
wxDirectoriesEnumerator traverser(&dirList);
wxDir dir("C:\\Folder1");
if (dir.IsOpened()) {
    dir.Traverse(traverser);
    ListBox1->Clear();
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<dirList.GetCount(); i++) {
        //The name is what follows the last \ or /
        ListBox1->Append(dirList.Item(i).AfterLast('\\').AfterLast('/'));
    }
}
```

I think you'll want to replace `ListBox1` with `m_lbDir`, if that's the name of your ListBox.