# Iterate directories non-recursively in c++ wxDir

Tags: c++, directory, wxwidgets

I'm trying to iterate a directory and list all folders inside.
I checked on the [wx documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.3/classwx_dir.html#adf11b6104db3ff8c17902328d0ada848) and used `GetAllFiles`

currently I use:

```
wxArrayString files;
size_t n, i;

n = wxDir::GetAllFiles("c:/temp/", &files, wxEmptyString, wxDIR_DIRS);

for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    myOwnPrint("folders: %s", files.Item(i));
}
```

and it lists all directories and the subdirectories inside..

what I want is just to list all the outer folders..

I checked the [wxDirFlags](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.3/dir_8h.html#aa45988fae9ce0d0c4f8312a6cf026232) but I think that there is no flag that only lists directories non-recursively.

Any ideas?

Comment: It says "should include wxDIR_DIRS flag to recurse into subdirectories". Why don't you try wxDIR_FILES?

Comment: yes, I also tried wxDIR_FILES, however it only lists files, and not folders. what I want is to list folders..

Comment: Can you just use `GetFirst` and `GetNext` in a loop?

Comment: You could always filter the directories yourself.

Comment: @TheDark, I also did look on `GetFirst` and `GetNext`, but haven't used it.. I think I'll try it.
@Devolus, do you mean the 3rd argument on the `GetAllFiles` function?

Comment: @TheDark, tried using `GetFirst` and `GetNext`, however you need to change the `cwd` in order to use it.. I think I'll pass on this method.

Comment: There is an example in this thread that does it without cwd. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166016/making-a-list-of-folders-in-a-directory-with-wxwidgets

Comment: @TheDark, I saw the code and I think it works good.. however I'm still wondering if there's any way `GetAllFiles` might be used non-recursively.. well if there's no other better answers suggested here I guess I'll try using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAllFiles()` is a helper method allowing to avoid having to define a `wxDirTraverser`-derived class when you're doing the recursive directory traversal, so it doesn't make much sense for it to not recurse -- this is what is there for.

For a simple iteration over files and/or directories in the given directory, just use `GetFirst()` and `GetNext()` as already mentioned in the comments:

```
wxDir dir(path);
if ( !dir.IsOpened() ) {
   ... handle error ...
}
wxString subdir;
for ( bool cont = dir.GetFirst(&subdir, wxString(), wxDIR_DIRS);
      cont;
      cont = dir.GetNext(&subdir) ) {
   ... do whatever you need to do with subdir ...
}
```